# How to make non editable text field which is front of slider .?

Tags: jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="slider-2">Input slider:</label>
  <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="25" min="0" max="100" />
</div>
```

Hi 
is it possible to make non editable (user not able to change text field ) which is display front of slider  using jquery mobile?

secondly how to reset the value of slider on click button..?

I have one more problem How to set current date on text field(on openng pop up screen) using datebox ?
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/uhdYv/

I open the pop up screen using (+) Button i need to set current date on date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for hide slider text box you can do it by CSS

```
<style type=text/css>
input.ui-slider-input {
    display : none !important;
}
</style>
```

or if u want to keep visible but not editable then
try this

```
<input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="25" min="0" max="100" onkeypress="return false;"/>
```

here **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/neXCm/1/)**

for reset the slider value

```
.slider("refresh");
```

here is link [Slider](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-slider.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `disabled` attribute will make it non-editable.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <label for="slider-2">Input slider:</label>
  <input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="25" min="0"  max="100" disabled />
</div>
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btSnP/)

I tried `.slider("refresh")` but it is not working.  So made a small work around like

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
$('input').val('');
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/btSnP/2/)

Comment: But i don't need this..i will explain again : there is label then text  field then slider ..But when i change slider it value change on text field it is fine .But user click on text field (write any thing )  But i don't want this.

Comment: user able to write anything on textfield (like abc ).I don't need that

Comment: @Rohit But I don't find any text field in your code.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: here 25 is written in front of slider .And it editable.User able to change (25 to abc )anything .i need it change only when slider change but not external

Comment: please give me any idea of this question..?

Comment: @Rohit can we have something like `$('input.ui-input-text.ui-slider-input').prop('disabled', true);`?

Comment: ok i am trying..!!I have one more problem How to set current date on text field(on openng pop up screen) using datebox ? http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/uhdYv/

Comment: It disable the hole slider..:(